# Using iterative projection to solve a minimization problem

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

Given matrices $\Gamma_1, C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, find a matrix $\Gamma \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ that minimizes the matrix norm of $\Gamma - \Gamma_1$ subject to constraints

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \Gamma - \Gamma_1 \|\\ \text{subject to} & \Gamma 1_n = 1_n\\ & \Gamma^{\top} 1_n = 1_n\\ & C \Gamma = 1_n 1_n^{\top}\end{array}$$

How can I solve it using MATLAB? I find someone uses Iterative Bregman Projections. Or can this be solved by using proximal methods?

Are there any methods to solve it. It's very important for my current research. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: How is the KL divergence defined when the inputs are matrices, rather than distributions?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo   KL divergence in matrix can be just replaced by norm($Γ-Γ_1$)

Comment: l1-norm or frobenius norm are both OK for my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed it. Constraint 3 means that each term in the matrix is in the value of 1.

Comment: Small remark that is probably not relevant: if $C$ is invertible, this problem suddenly becomes a lot simpler...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hi, could you help me with another question on the website  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266998/how-to-solve-this-matrix-optimization-problem

Answer (score 1):

Given matrices $\mathrm X_0, \mathrm C \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm X - \mathrm X_0 \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X 1_n = 1_n\\ & 1_n^{\top} \mathrm X = 1_n^{\top}\\ & \mathrm C \mathrm X = 1_n 1_n^{\top}\end{array}$$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), $\tilde{\mathrm x} := \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)$, we obtain the following convex **quadratic program** (QP)

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \tilde{\mathrm x} \|_2^2 - 2 \langle \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X_0), \tilde{\mathrm x} \rangle + \| \mathrm X_0 \|_{\text{F}}^2\\ \text{subject to} & (1_n^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n ) \, \tilde{\mathrm x} = 1_n\\ & (\mathrm I_n \otimes 1_n^{\top}) \, \tilde{\mathrm x} = 1_n\\ & (\mathrm I_n \otimes \mathrm C) \, \tilde{\mathrm x} = 1_{n^2}\end{array}$$

In MATLAB, use function [quadprog](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) to solve this QP. Then use `reshape` to un-vectorize the solution.

Comment: I think you have helped me to solve it. Thanks very much for your kindness.

Comment: You need MATLAB's Optimization Toolbox, though.

Comment: I test this, but matlab shows that the dual problem is suspected of being infeasible.  May be the constraint 3  violates with the other two constraints.

Comment: There are $n^2$ unknowns. The first two (vector) constraints impose $2n$ (scalar) constraints. The third (matrix) constraint imposes $n^2$ (scalar) constraints. The system is *overdetermined*. Hence, infeasibility should come as no surprise.

Comment: In fact, if the system is infeasible, perhaps it would make more sense to solve the regularized least-squares problem $$\text{minimize} \qquad \| \mathrm X 1_n - 1_n \|_2^2 + \| \mathrm X^{\top} 1_n - 1_n \|_2^2 + \| \mathrm C \mathrm X - 1_n 1_n^{\top} \|_{\text{F}}^2 + \gamma \| \mathrm X - \mathrm X_0 \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

Comment: Thanks very much. I think there is an error in the mathematical modeling for  my problem.

Comment: This is why it is a good idea to provide motivation when asking a question. People can help refine the question before attempting to answer it.