# How to solve this matrix optimization problem?

Tags: matrices, combinatorial-optimization

$$\min_{X,P} \| X D + (P X P') \, D_0 \|_{\text{F}}$$

where $X$ is a symmetric matrix and $P$ is a permutation matrix. $D$ and $D_0$ are given symmetric matrices. Is there some way to solve this problem?  Adding some other constraints may also be allowed.

Comment: What is a costant matrix?

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I mean they are constant.

Comment: How big are the matrices?

Comment: What is the background? Motivation? Context? Where does this come from?